# Determine current domain controller programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, domaincontroller, domainservices

I need to query current domain controller, probably primary to change user password.

(P)DC name should be fully qualified, i.e. `DC=pdc,DC=example,DC=com` (how to properly name such notation?)

How can it be done using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(requires System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll):

```
using (var context = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    string server = context.ConnectedServer; // "pdc.examle.com"
    string[] splitted = server.Split('.'); // { "pdc", "example", "com" }
    IEnumerable<string> formatted = splitted.Select(s => String.Format("DC={0}", s));// { "DC=pdc", "DC=example", "DC=com" }
    string joined = String.Join(",", formatted); // "DC=pdc,DC=example,DC=com"

    // or just in one string

    string pdc = String.Join(",", context.ConnectedServer.Split('.').Select(s => String.Format("DC={0}", s)));
}
```

Comment: This won't work for a cross-domain situation (e.g. your machine isn't part of the domain where the Domain Controller exists).  See my answer for such a solution.

Answer (score 6):

To retrieve the information when the `DomainController` exists in a Domain in which your machine doesn't belong, you need something more.

```
  DirectoryContext domainContext =  new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "targetDomainName", "validUserInDomain", "validUserPassword");

  var domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(domainContext);
  var controller = domain.FindDomainController();
```

Comment: I don't want to pass user name and password.

Comment: Unfortunately if you're crossing domains, you need to.  Your existing Identity won't be recognized otherwise.  Even with the "new" 3.5 `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace you would have to include a valid username/password on the *external* domain.

Comment: This doesn't work because your local computer will not be able to find a DC for that domain.

Answer (score 2):

We are using something like this for our internal applications.

Should return something like `DC=d,DC=r,DC=ABC,DC=com`

```
public static string RetrieveRootDseDefaultNamingContext()
{
    String RootDsePath = "LDAP://RootDSE";
    const string DefaultNamingContextPropertyName = "defaultNamingContext";

    DirectoryEntry rootDse = new DirectoryEntry(RootDsePath)
    {
        AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
    };
    object propertyValue = rootDse.Properties[DefaultNamingContextPropertyName].Value;

    return propertyValue != null ? propertyValue.ToString() : null;
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right.  We normally have some custom logging code in the catch statement but I took it out for this example.

Comment: @abatishchev: that statement is wrong - calling just `throw` will **preserve** the stack trace; creating a new exception or doing `throw ex;` would break the call stack; see: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx

Comment: @marc_s: yea, you're right, i was wrong (in phrase about stack trace). anyway this makes no sense until logging, etc as @Lareau said

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to interact the Active Directory, you shouldn't have to know where the [FSMO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779716%28WS.10%29.aspx) roles are for the most part. If you want to change the AD topology from your program (I wouldn't), look at the [DomainController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2218ffz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class.

If you want to change a user password, you can invoke those actions on the User object, and Active Directory will make sure that the changes are properly replicated.

copied from http://www.rootsilver.com/2007/08/how-to-change-a-user-password

```
public static void ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
{
        string path = "LDAP://CN=" + userName + ",CN=Users,DC=demo,DC=domain,DC=com";

        //Instantiate a new DirectoryEntry using an administrator uid/pwd
        //In real life, you'd store the admin uid/pwd  elsewhere
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, "administrator", "password");

        try
        {
           directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[]{oldPassword, newPassword});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  //TODO: catch a specific exception ! :)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("success");
}
```

Comment: how do you think, can I change my current password using my own user name and current password?