# Active Directory Get Domain from Computer that is not on Domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

My computer is on domain A, I am trying to get domain B by doing the following:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

.
.
.

DirectoryContext directoryContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainName, user, pass);
using (var domain = Domain.GetDomain(directoryContext))
{
    ...
}
```

When I do this Domain.GetDomain(directoryContext) throws an ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException.  My machine that I am running from is on a totally separate domain.  The domain I am trying to connect to is a test domain.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  Is there some sort of network configuration that needs to be set to enable this?

Comment: does the Domain that you are on have `AD`..? also are you familiar with `PrincipalContext` I find it much easier to use personally..

Comment: Yes it does, both domain A and B have AD.  How would I do this with PrincipalContext?

Comment: by doing a google search but here is a link to get you started.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015407/determine-current-domain-controller-programmatically